# Playa fields not parsing tags

Tags: playa, parsing

after moving my site from one production environment to another, Im getting strange results in a Playa field.  the tags are not being parsed, but values have been set.  what causes this sort of behavior? where the `{product_vineyard_appellation}` tags are not being parsed in the if conditional.

this is the output on the site:

```
{product_vineyard_appellation}
  <dt>Appellation</dt>
  <dd><a href="LINK" class="vineyard-appellation" id="ID">Estate Malbec</a></dd>
{/product_vineyard_appellation}
```

and this is the template

```
{if product_vineyard_appellation}
  {product_vineyard_appellation}
  <dt>{if channel_short_name == "vineyards"}Vineyard{if:else}Appellation{/if}</dt>
    <dd><a href="/our-story/{channel_short_name}/{url_title}" class="vineyard-appellation">{title}</a></dd>
  {/product_vineyard_appellation}
{/if}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, I'm having the same problem...